# AS3: class not functioning properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Sorry for a blurry title, but this is probably the best way I can describe the issue that seems absurd to me by now.

I need a simple action done by an MC: going to a certain frame. I couldn't get it to work, although I had an exact same type of action done by another Movie Clip in the same class code. Here's how I did it:

```
if (currentItem.type == "blue") {
    guy.gotoAndPlay("blue")
}
```

Yes, the class I'm referring to ('guy') is extended as a Movie Clip. Again, exact same code works fine with other Clips. I tried another method: switching the frame from the Clip's class, the frame it switches to is defined by a variable which is changed by main class. But somehow, this doesn't work either. It gives me the 1069 error. Here's the code of the 'guy' class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class guy extends MovieClip 
    {

        public static var gotoer:String = "fffuuu"

        public function shaman_armsUp() 
        {
            super();
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
        }

        public function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
            armLoop()
        }

        public function armLoop():void {
            if (gotoer == "brown") {
                this.gotoAndPlay("brown")
            }
            if (gotoer == "red") {
                trace(gotoer)
                this.gotoAndPlay("red")
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Is there anyone who has a logical explanation for this? Can this be caused by a bug?

Comment: please tell us what line throws the error and what the actual error message is. I don't know what error #1069 means without starting an online search.

Comment: ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property gotoer on guy.
 at Main/throwingFunction()
 at Main/mainLoop()

I tried stating the variable both as 'public static var' and 'public var', neither worked. Also I googled up a suggestion that "Automatically declare stage instances" checkbox in AS3 settings may be unchecked, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the code you are writing in the method shaman_armsUp() should be moved to the constructor?

Follow my edited version of your class guy (also, renamed to Guy, follow the class name convention)

```
package
{
     import flash.display.FrameLabel;
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.events.Event;

     // renaming the class name (guy to Guy)
     public class Guy extends MovieClip
     {
         // not sure if using an static variable for this case is the best idea, but I decided to keep because I don't know your initial idea
         public static var gotoer:String = "fffuuu";

         public function Guy()
         {
             // move the addedToStage event to the constructor
             super();
             addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);
         }

         public function shaman_armsUp()
         {
         }

         public function init(e:Event):void
         {
              removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
              armLoop();
         }

         public function armLoop():void
         {
              // Note: the value of gotoer is "fffuuu" and there is no conditional for it.
             // are you chaging this value before calling armLoop? because when the init method is called it has the same value

             // why not try something like:

             // checking if the frame exist and if so, calling the gotoAndPlay method (try to imagine if you have 100 frame names? the old approach will be very hard to maintain

             if (hasFrameLabel(gotoer))
             {
                  this.gotoAndPlay(gotoer);
             }
             else
             {
                  trace('frame: ', gotoer, ' not found');
             }

            /*
            if (gotoer == "brown")
            {
               this.gotoAndPlay("brown");
            }
            if (gotoer == "red")
            {
               trace(gotoer);
               this.gotoAndPlay("red");
            }
            */
         }

         // helper function to avoid calling a frame that doesn't exist
         private function hasFrameLabel(frameLabel:String):Boolean
         {
              var returnValue:Boolean;

              const obj:Object = this.currentLabels;

              for each (var i:FrameLabel in obj)
              {
                  if (i.name == frameLabel)
                  {
                      returnValue = true;
                      break;
                  }
               }

               return returnValue;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't fix the issue. The problem is that I can't address the 'gotoer' value from Main class for some reason. It won't accept a direct gotoAndPlay command nor value change. It feels like I didn't state that Guy is a MovieClip (I did) or something.

Comment: it's hard to test without having the entire scope. If you try to add a string argument in your armLoop method? passing the frame label?

Comment: Okay, after messing around for a while, I fixed the problem. Sorry, but I'm not experienced in AS3 enough yet to clearly tell what the problem was, but I suspect it was about calling a goto function from somewhere else already. Thanks for your advice, gPeart.